# How to Redirect User from Http to Https page in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

Hi I have a scenario where I want to redirect the user from Html page `http://localhost:9091/Sample/Home.html` to the another JSP page which is HTTPS: after clicking on Login button I want to redirect the user to HTTPS page.

Comment: In your html page in `action=name-of-page.jsp` put name of jsp page!

Comment: but how to make that JSP page run with HTTPS ?

Comment: which server you are using?

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/563891/JSP/java/https-JSP this has exactly same discussion going on!

Comment: I am using Tomcat server 7.0

Comment: Please follow this link http://tkurek.blogspot.in/2013/07/tomcat-7-http-to-https-redirect.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Http to https redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991640/http-to-https-redirection)

Comment: Just use HTTPS period.  Doing the login over HTTP and then redirecting to HTTPS is NOT secure.  You'll be sending the user's username and password over HTTP as plaintext, and then encrypting the pages after login.  Kinda defeats the point. You need to start the encryption BEFORE the user sends their username/password so that their password isn't floating around the internet in plain text.